# Yii - Gridview with audio player in each data row

Tags: audio, gridview, widget, yii2, playback

I have a gridview that display's audio path's stored in database model, and then grabs it's file in the path attached to a play button to simply play the audio file.

[image]

**Here is the code:**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'nome',
        //'ficheiro',
        [
            'label' => '',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=> function($data) { return Html::a('&#9658;',$data->ficheiro); },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => ''],
    ],
]); ?>
```

But now i changed my mind and wanted to implement inside the gridview, instead of the the play button, some kind of widget or audio player with button and perhaps percentage of file listened.

Just like spotify or similar.

**Tried to embed as value => field of the widget: yii2-jplayer-widget pointing to a audio file, but it didn't accept it, and throws error.**

**Here is the code to embed a player widget in the Gridview (didn't work):**

```
'value'=> AudioJs::widget(['files'=>'1.mp3']),
```

It throws error: Getting unknown property: app\models\Faixas::

I thank for any ideas that help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not a html5 audio player

```
  'value' => function ($model) {                      
              return "<audio controls='controls'>
                        <source src='" . $model->ficheiro  .   "' type='audio/mp3' />
                       </audio>" ;
            },
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, it worked only in files that don't have spaces in the file name. Example: Captain of the heart.mp3 doesn't play because of the spaces between words.

Comment: I have update the answer adding quote before and after the filename.

Comment: It worked very well. Many thanks :) Another question, it is possible to play automatically the next audio element when the previous is done? Maybe with javascript?

Comment: Next audio element, you mean the audio in the next row?

Comment: Yes -> audio in the next row.

Comment: In this moment i don't have the code but anyway In javascript you can intercept the `ended` event specified for video or audio element. and start the next audio with the `play()` method. see MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement for reference